# Accessing SharedPreferences before displaying the first activity?

Tags: android

In my application, I'd like to access SharedPreferences before displaying the first Activity (this should be done to determine whether the user is "logged in" or not, and then either display the login screen or the main screen). Can this be achieved? Or do I have to make a short splash screen to cover up the clutter?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:
Make a SplashScreen Activity and test there if the user is logged in and then decide which Activity to show. If you just check the SharedPreferences you can also display just a black View, it will display such a short time, the user won't notice.

You can do it also in your fist Activities' onCreate Method before `setContentView` and then decide which View to show.

Answer (score 0):

Just access `SharedPreferences` inside `onCreate()` method of Login activity. Check if the user has logged in. If yes, go to Main activity. If not, then we already are in Login page. In this case when the user logs in, set the "loggenIn" to `True` in SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences sp =  referenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

if(sp.getBoolean("loggedIn",false)){  //if the user is logged in
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class); // go to the Main page
        Login.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my application, I'd like to access SharedPreferences before displaying the first Activity (this should be done to determine whether the user is "logged in" or not, and then either display the login screen or the main screen). Can this be achieved?

Well, not really, since the way a user enters your app is via some "main" activity, the user necessarily has to start *something* before you can do anything.

> Or do I have to make a short splash screen to cover up the clutter?

You have 3 options:

1. Splash Screen as you suggested: detect login state, open login or main activity, finish yourself.
2. MainActivity: check if logged in, if not, open LoginActivity and check result. If user logged in continue, if not exit or otherwise handle failure.
3. Log in activity: check if logged in, if so, open Main and finish yourself.

Personally I would choose option (3) since a log in activity would be doing this "redirect on log in" logic anyway and means you don't need to have the splash screen or clutter main with  login logic checks. But follow your heart.

Hope that helps!